# Import JSON to html (table) filtering results

Tags: javascript, html, json, import, html-table

I'm trying to import JSON data to a html table. I have different types of data. In my case I need only  to see the "link" data type in a table this is the JSON data I'm getting.

```
  {   "data": [
  {
     "type": "photo",
     "created_time": "2017-11-15T14:30:43+0000",
     "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/LaFokaES/posts/693061044378702",
     "shares": {
        "count": 2270
     },
     "id": "104957429855736_693061044378702"
  },
  {
     "type": "link",
     "created_time": "2017-11-15T02:34:46+0000",
     "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/LaFokaES/posts/692656794419127",
     "shares": {
        "count": 86
     },
     "id": "104957429855736_692656794419127"
  },
  {
     "type": "photo",
     "created_time": "2017-11-15T00:34:50+0000",
     "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/LaFokaES/posts/692493157768824",
     "shares": {
        "count": 1628
     },
     "id": "104957429855736_692493157768824"
  },
  {
     "type": "photo",
     "created_time": "2017-11-14T23:51:53+0000",
     "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/LaFokaES/posts/692442954440511",
     "shares": {
        "count": 6239
     },
     "id": "104957429855736_692442954440511"
```

This is the code I have:

```
   <body>
    <input type="text" class="txtPagina">
    <button class="btnBuscar">Buscar</button>
    <table class="tabla" border='1'>
         <tr>

             <td>Type</td>
          <td>created time</td>
             <td>permalink url</td>
             <td>Shares Count</td>


         </tr>
    </table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btnBuscar').on('click', function (){
                var pagina = $('.txtPagina').val();
            //Ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+pagina+"/feed?fields=type,created_time,permalink_url,shares&limit=25& access_token=(mytoken)",
                success: function(data){


     $.each(data.data, function(i, d){
        var s = d.shares ? '<td>'+d.shares.count+'</td>' : '';
        $('.tabla').append('<tr><td>'+d.type+'</td><td>'+d.created_time+'</td><td>'+d.permalink_url+'</td>'+s+'</tr>');
      });
    },
                    error: function (){
                        console.log("Error");
```

And this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see I'm getting photos and links but I need to see only links.

Comment: wouldn't just `'<a href="'+d.permalink_url+'>'+d.permalink_url+'</a>'` suffice?

Comment: What do mean "I need to see only links"? Isn't it your own code? Change it so it shows you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement in your loop to filter out the photos.

```
 $.each(data.data, function(i, d){
      if(d.type =='link'){
      var s = d.shares ? '<td>'+d.shares.count+'</td>' : '';
    $('.tabla').append('<tr><td>'+d.type+'</td><td>'+d.created_time+'</td><td>'+d.permalink_url+'</td>'+s+'</tr>');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your each loop:

```
if(d.type == 'link') {
    //Add as you already do
}
```

Done!